# Is it possible to schedule posts with Jekyll?

Tags: blogs, jekyll, static-pages

I suspect that one of the limitations of running a static site is that the administrator has to be at the helm when he wants a post to be published. I'm looking for that suspicion to be validated. Is there a method I haven't discovered?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the site.future option to false on the _config.yml file.

Then set up a cron task in your server to regenerate your blog every day (or hour, whatever you fancy).

Posts set up in the future will be automatically published when the correct date is reached.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted my own answer because some independent testing gave results that made me think I was wrong, but I will experiment later to see what happened.

Comment: Can I do it with GitHub pages?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov probably, but I have not tried. If you do, please report your findings.

Comment: Probably not working with github pages because AFAIK, github only regenerate the pages when your push something. So if you want to do this you'll have to push something and, hopefully, github will regenerate your site

Comment: In order for this to work you need to have some sort of automatic scheduler in your own machine which periodically publishes the jekyll site to the server - github or otherwise. I suggested [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), but there are others.